# Aligning multiple inline image blocks to the left and right

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I am trying to align multiple inline images, five to the left, and one to the right (the signature), preferably without the use of floats. All images should be vertically aligned (from the top). I hear flex-box is an option, but am having difficulty implementing it correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/z5h1tfnt/5/

```
<html>

<style>
/* Social Media Buttons */
.social_media_logos { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px; 

}

#signature{
    vertical-align: top;
}

</style>

<div class="social_media_logos">

    <!-- LinkedIn -->
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mahdi-al-husseini-0aa98678/"><img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4292/35304750524_b7a7b46958_o.png" alt="" width= "50" height= "50" /></a>

    <!-- Instagram -->
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/alhusseinimahdi/"><img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4296/36011295361_36583c28fb_o.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" /></a>

    <!-- GitHub -->
    <a href="https://github.com/csapidus"><img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4425/36376344962_247a7a8266_o.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" /></a>

    <!-- News Columns -->
    <a href="columns.html"><img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4335/36124335440_ba8c32d082_o.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" /></a>

    <!-- Resume -->
    <img id="Img1" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4299/36105742616_d3fe406198_o.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" />

    <!-- Signature -->
    <img id = "signature" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4350/36527270485_2b7a1d8506_o.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" /> 

</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's a solution using `flexbox`:

1. Add `display: flex` to the `social_media_logos` and give it `align-items: center` for *vertical alignment*.
2. Add `margin-left: auto` to push the *signature* to the right and the other icons to the left.

See demo below:

```css
/* Social Media Buttons */
.social_media_logos { 
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

#signature{
   margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="social_media_logos">
            
    <!-- LinkedIn -->
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mahdi-al-husseini-0aa98678/"><img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4292/35304750524_b7a7b46958_o.png" alt="" width= "50" height= "50" /></a>

    <!-- Instagram -->
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/alhusseinimahdi/"><img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4296/36011295361_36583c28fb_o.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" /></a>

    <!-- GitHub -->
    <a href="https://github.com/csapidus"><img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4425/36376344962_247a7a8266_o.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" /></a>

    <!-- News Columns -->
    <a href="columns.html"><img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4335/36124335440_ba8c32d082_o.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" /></a>

    <!-- Resume -->
    <img id="Img1" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4299/36105742616_d3fe406198_o.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" />

    <!-- Signature -->
    <img id = "signature" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4350/36527270485_2b7a1d8506_o.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" /> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .social_media_logos {
        display: flex;
        margin: 0 5px;
        width: 100%;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="social_media_logos">
        <div>
            <!-- LinkedIn -->
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mahdi-al-husseini-0aa98678/">
                <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4292/35304750524_b7a7b46958_o.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
            </a>

            <!-- Instagram -->
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/alhusseinimahdi/">
                <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4296/36011295361_36583c28fb_o.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
            </a>

            <!-- GitHub -->
            <a href="https://github.com/csapidus">
                <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4425/36376344962_247a7a8266_o.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
            </a>

            <!-- News Columns -->
            <a href="columns.html">
                <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4335/36124335440_ba8c32d082_o.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
            </a>

            <!-- Resume -->
            <img id="Img1" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4299/36105742616_d3fe406198_o.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" /> 
        </div>

        <!-- Signature -->
        <img id="signature" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4350/36527270485_2b7a1d8506_o.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" /> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wrapped all the icons on the left in a container and pushed the signature and the icon container to the inner outside of the main container with flex box.